# How can I fine tune K means clustering when I'm only getting clusters in lines?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

It's my first time trying to do K-Means clustering using Python and Sci-Kit Learn and I don't know what to make of my final cluster plot or how to fine tune my K means clustering algorithm.

My end goal is to find a clustering of user categories that delineates some interesting or useful behavior traits.

ATTEMPT 1:

Input: Gender, Age Range, Country (all one hot encoded because the data is categorical), and Account Age (numerical in weeks old)

[image]

Code:

```
# Convert DataFrame to matrix
mat2 = all_dummy.as_matrix()
# Using sklearn
km2 = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=6)
km2.fit(mat2)
# Get cluster assignment labels
labels2 = km2.labels_
# Format results as a DataFrame
results2 = pd.DataFrame([all_dummy.index,labels2]).T

plot_x2 = results2[0].tolist()
plot_y2 = results2[1].tolist()
pyplot.scatter(plot_x2,plot_y2)
pyplot.show()
```

Plot:

[image]

Specific Questions:

1. What is the X and Y axis of this graph?
2. What is this graph even telling me?
3. Why are there only 3 clusters showing up when I put 6 clusters as an input? (answered by first comment and updated code and graph)
4. How can I fine tune this graph to tell me more and show me a useful relationship if I don't know what the relationship I am looking for is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read up on the limitations of k-means.

In particular, be aware that

1. you must remove all identifier columns
2. k-means is *very* sensitive to scale. All attributes need to be carefully scaled according to their value range, distribution, and importance. Preprocessing is essential!
3. k-means assumes *continuous* variables. The use on categorical data, even when one-hot encoded, is questionable. It sometimes works "okayish" but barely ever workd "good".

Answer (score 2):

1. According to your code, the X axis corresponds to the indices of your samples (seeing your graph, I suppose you have around 10 000 users then), and the Y axis corresponds to the labels of each sample.
2. You might not have 6 clusters as an input. Indeed, when you format your results as a dataframe, a **labels** variable is used, while it is actually **labels2** that contain the computed cluster assignments. I don't know where your **labels** come from, but I suspect this is the reason you obtain those results. Hence, regarding question 2, this graph *probably* doesn't show anything relevant.
3. You first could use other visualisations to better understand how your data is being clustered. Sklearn's documentation provides many examples you could use for inspiration ([1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_iris.html), [2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_stock_market.html), [3](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_assumptions.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-kmeans-assumptions-py)).

Hope it helped !